# the difference between " in front of " & "at the front of"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two?

- at the front of the cinema
- in front of the cinema

Is it a matter of AmE and BrE?

Comment: I (BrE) would understand the first to mean 'in one of the front rows of seats' and the second 'on the street at the front of the building'.

Answer (score 2):

- "In front of" is a position *relative* to something else.
- "At the front of" is a position *within* something as a whole.

So, "*in front of the cinema*" would normally mean you were standing outside of the cinema building. "*At the front of the cinema*" would mean that your position within the cinema was at the front. Idiomatically, I would take this to mean you were sitting on the front row of a cinema screen.

Note that some people also say "*out front of...*" to mean they are outside of a building's entrance. This is chiefly American English.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two phrases have different meanings. They are both used in BrE and AmE.

> I park my car **in front of the cinema**.

> **At the front of the cinema** is the entrance lobby and ticket booth.

*in front* of means **outside of and at the front** in some way, in the street, in the front garden (BrE) / front yard (AmE), or placing one object in front of another.

> I put my arm chair **in front of** the television set.

*at the front of* usually refers to some part of an object or building but part of it

> **At the front of** the house is the lounge and dining rooms.

> **At the front of** my TV set is the on/off switch.